# Getting help keeping whitespace from Avro Deserialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

We have an app that uses the avro-maven-plugin. We are using kafka to consume from topics and receieve events that contain data in avro format. The data consists of things like addresses so when the user enters data and they put their address in, they may type "450 SpongeBob Boulevard" but our app receives it as "450SpongeBobBoulevard". We want to do validations on the address and check to see if certain things are valid, but it has become very difficult now that it all comes in as one string. Is there a good process or configuration I can use to keep the whitespace?

I've tried creating a parser method that can tell if something ends in Road or Way and can tell if it starts with a number, then i can assign these values to an array, but now im running into things like PO box and N S E W (North South East West) and im not sure this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: 1) What version of Avro are you using 2) Please show a [mcve]. That plugin does not remove whitespace, only creates a schema that your Java classes can use... Maybe your own serialization process is the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.